# Standard defining json file extensions?

Tags: json, specifications, file-format, standards-compliance

Is there a standard or specification which defines json file extensions?

I've seen `.json` used - is this just a commonly accepted practice or is it a requirement of some standards body for json saved in file format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Douglas Crockford's draft of the JSON format found [here](http://www.json.org/draft-crockford-jsonorg-json-04.txt):

> "A JSON parser transforms a JSON text
>   into another representation. A
>   JSON parser MUST accept all texts that
>   conform to the JSON grammar. A JSON
>   parser MAY accept non-JSON forms or
>   extensions."

So, it's just a commonly-accepted practice; as long as your file conforms to the JSON grammar the extension doesn't necessarily need to be *.json (although it can certainly be helpful to you and other developers if it is).